# How to read names of .txt files from multiple folders and subfolders and write them to multiple .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, svm, tfidfvectorizer

I have multiple extracted .txt files in subfolders of a folder. Subfolder name is nothing but the name of the extracted .pdf, .txt files are the files which has text from each page of a pdf in a seperate text file.

Example:

Extracted: myFile.pdf which has 10 pages so it was extracted to 10 .txt files into following folders,
Output Folder --> myFile Folder --> [csv Folder, json Folder, txtFiles folder]

my target 10 text files are in "txtFiles Folder"
I have 100's of such pdf files and text files in 100's of folders

I did it to classify each page in the pdf document using linear SVM model. Now I have classified labels for the target text files come from the ML model.

Here I am trying to create a .csv file with .pdf file name or 2nd Folder name for each file and write page number and concerned prediction label into the .csv file.

```
filename = []
clfLabel = []
for root, dir, files in os.walk(folderPath):
    for name in files:
        if name endswith((".txt")):
            file = os.sep.join([root, name])
            with open(file) as textFile:
            text = textFile.read()
            cleanText = preprocessText(text)
            cleanText = [cleanText]
            tfidfText = loaded_vectorizer.transform(cleanText)
            predicted = svcModelpkl.predict(tfidfText)
            prediction = encoder.inverse_transform(predicted)
            filename.append(name)
            clfLabel.append(prediction)
            fileName = pd.DataFrame(filename)
            clfLabel = pd.Dataframe(clfLabel)
            data = pd.concat(["fileName", "clfLabel"], axis = 1, ignore = index, sort = False)
            data.columns = ["fileName", "clfLabel"]
            data.to_csv(name+".csv")
```

here I am looking to create a seperate .csv file for each pdf or Folder with the same name with page numbers and their predictions

myfile.pdf has 10 pages
anotherfile.pdf has 15 pages

myFile.csv

| pageNum | DocLabel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Doc_A |
| 2 | Doc_B |
| 3 | Doc_C |
| 4 | Doc_A |
| 5 | Doc_C |
| 6 | Doc_B |
| 7 | Doc_D |
| 8 | Doc_C |
| 9 | Doc_A |
| 10 | Doc_D |

anotherfile.csv
etc....

I am new to python please help me in achieving this

Comment: What is actually the problem? You mentioned what u're trying to do, but not the actual place where you got stuck. Ultimately, doing multiple read -> multiple write is essentially the same as doing just one read -> write successfully and iterate across all cases.

Comment: I don't know how to create a csv with folder name and print the textfile_01.txt page number which is the number in the name 01 and corresponding prediction label

Comment: To get the folder name you can use the `Path` object: `from pathlib import Path`. Take a look at this reference: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter9/ in the section "Getting the Parts of a File Path". Then, take a look at "Writing to files" at the same chapter to add the information you need. In fact, if you're new to python I would highly recommend looking at the other chapters as well, there's plenty of good stuff in there.